# Does the virial theorem prohibit dark matter BH's on any size or timescale, or just make them very unlikely?

Tags: black-holes, universe, big-bang, dark-matter

I've read other Q's on dark matter/black holes, but none seem to be technically specific enough to clarify this point.

I understand so far, that because classic CDM doesn't interact in ways that allow it to divest itself of substantial energy, any attempt to condense gravitationally beyond a fairly low degree,  would  result in higher average KE and loss of particles from the compacting body, which therefore cannot form. I gather this is essentially the virial theorem at work.

But it's not clear to me, how absolute a barrier this is, within the constraints of current knowledge and models.

(Clearly we're on the cusp of unknown laws of nature in this question, I'm assuming no new physics beyond what is well enough reputed to have been researched in depth. So "If  SM/SUSY is correct" or "if L-CDM is correct"=OK, "If handwaving magic/physics in the year 2500/future cosmology says X"= not OK, roughly speaking)

For example, a BH is simply a certain amount of matter within a certain size spherical space (for simplicity) - a sufficiently large BH would in theory allow one to traverse its event horizon and one wouldn't even be aware of it. So presumably **physical scale** might change the answer, and current models would allow for a huge amount of very diffuse matter/energy to meet that criterion. Similarly but less well understood, under extreme **early-universe conditions** do our models suggest much scope for energy levels and quantum fields to form either micro/small BH's from what we know of candidate DM particles?  Another route might be the fact we refer to **"average" KE** not minimum or maximum, in the 1st paragraph above - there will be variation. This one seems statistically incredibly unlikely but I don't know the statistics - what scope exists in current models for DM BH's to be somewhat plausible on any sane timescale (say arbitrarily < `O(0.1 - 1)` trillion years)? Another route might be **timescale** - over a similar timescale do any routes we currently understand via particle physics allow for the formation of more than a tiny number of BH's? Finally, perhaps **"well studied variants" of the SM**, such as SUSY, or different Higgs models, might influence the answer or allow for DM to have different properties that allow for BH structure formation.

I'm curious which of these routes, if any, rule in or out the possibility of DM BH's, and what if any conditions might be consistent with current knowledge and allow us to bypass virial, or if it's an absolute barrier so far as we know or seems likely.